# PHP Pear Mail - Include Path

Tags: php, email, pear

I am working on a PHP project that uses PHP's built in mail function. I am adding the option to use Pear mail.

It seems that in most hosting environments, using:

```
require_once('Mail.php')
```

doesn't work which is what all of the examples I could find show. Writing the include path as:

```
require_once('/path/to/pear/Mail.php')
```

also doesn't seem to work. However, setting the include path like:

```
set_include_path('/path/to/pear/')
require_once('Mail.php')
```

does work. Because there is a configuration file in my app where this is stored and the config is used in most of my pages (not having to do with email), I am not sure if this is a good idea. My config file now has the values stored like this:

```
// pear smtp mail settings
set_include_path('/path/to/pear/');
define('PEAR_INCLUDE_PATH', 'Mail.php');
define('SMTP_HOST', 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com');
define('SMTP_PORT', '465');
define('SMTP_USER', 'username@gmail.com');
define('SMTP_PASS', 'password');
```

Is this going to create problems for me? How should I do this?

Thank you

Comment: i don't think there is a problem, set include needed if not define in php.ini or apache config

Comment: If you're going to alter the include path, you should append to it not completely overwrite it: `set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'/path/to/pear/');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pear include path should be set globally in your php.ini file -- if not, you have a broken pear/php installation.

But if you want to be extra-paranoid, you could ship a local copy of pear's Mail and Net_SMTP modules.

Comment: Even in a hosting environment, the path should be set globally? Meaning that I shouldn't have to set the path just call Mail.php?

Comment: @user1002039 The [default value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) for `include_path` in php.ini is `.:/path/to/pear/` - if PEAR is not in the include path, it's not been installed correctly. FWIW, I prefer to use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) and ship it with my site code, rather than rely on PEAR which may or may not be installed

Comment: @DaveRandom, Thank you! In a hosting environment, do I have access to php.ini file?

Comment: @user1002039 That depends on the hosting environment, but probably not. However if it is Apache based you can probably [set it with a `.htaccess` file](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php). But even this relies on you knowing the install path of PEAR, which varies from server to server so you can't just ship a stock .htaccess, which is one reason I prefer PHPMailer (others also recommend [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)). Using a library that you can ship with your code means you don't have worry about the configuration of any given server.